# Is it possible for me to put a mask over a transparent image with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mask

I'm trying to make an overlay with a mask over a transparent image with ffmpeg, but the background of the image that gets the mask turns black, is there any way to make this background remain transparent?

`ffmpeg -i background.jpg -loop 1 -i image.png -loop 1 -i mask.png -filter_complex [0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=720:720[background];[2]alphaextract,scale=640x320[mask];[1]scale=640x320[image];[image][mask]alphamerge[final_mask];[background][final_mask]overlay=100:100[final] -map [final] -t 00:00:05.000 -y result.mp4`
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0jlo.png)

Comment: What is the format of the output? An image or a video? Can you post the input images?

Comment: The output is a video, in front of my code has a link written result, there is the output, screeshots of the images I used and the final video, I could not post them apart.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to create `MP4` video with transparent background.

Comment: But it's not the video I want transparent, just the overlay image with a mask

Comment: I recommend that you post  `background.jpg` and `image.png` (not a screeshot). I also recommend that you post `ffmpeg` command line that creates a `png` output, and not `mp4` (in case you only want an image).